# When the visibility of menu item is set to false it leaves a blank space

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, searchview

I have a function where I need a menu item to appear when the *searchView* is expanded and to disappear when the *searchView* is closed. I have *setVisible* as false for the item when expanded, it makes the menu item disappear on going back to collapsed state of *searchView* but it leaves a blank space.

Screenshots:

- https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbi1gr9j14e0hvi/stacksnip.JPG?dl=0
- https://www.dropbox.com/s/bc8tar3n6dkhn5f/stacksnip1.JPG?dl=0

Is there any option where the *searchView* icon can get back to its original place?

```
SearchManager searchManager =(SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    final MenuItem menuitem=menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final MenuItem locationitem=menu.findItem(R.id.action_location).setVisible(false);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuitem.getActionView();
    if(null!=searchManager ) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    }
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);   //if using on actionbar
    searchView.setClickable(true);
    searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
            // Your code here
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
            // Your code here
            return true;
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            populateAdapter(s);
            return false;
        }
    });
    searchView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) v;
            if (searchView.isIconified()) {

                locationitem.setVisible(false);

                Log.d("Trial","Working!!");
                fr=new Fragment_Two();
                FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragmentswitcher,fr);
                ft.commit();
            }
            else{
                locationitem.setVisible(true);
                Log.d("Trial","Working too!!");
                MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menuitem, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
                MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(locationitem, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
                fr=new Fragment_One();
                FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragmentswitcher,fr);
                ft.commit();
                View newView=fr.getView();

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Set the Visibility to NONE. That hides it and doesn't take up space.

Comment: First of all, thanks for such a quick response.I can not use setvisibility for menu items , so i have to use setvisible method which takes boolean parameters only , so just true or false. So how should i go about with that

Comment: i have the same problem :S

Comment: Is there really no solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, using `setVisible()` will hide the menu item, but the menu item will still take up space. You also cannot cast to a `View` object and use `setVisibility()` without a crash, either. I wasn't able to find documentation why, but I am sure it was designed this way intentionally.

To achieve the outcome of having menu items appear at times, and not at others, you need to make use of `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. Within this function, hide the menu items you don't wish to show based on whatever logic you like, and use the method `invalidateOptionsMenu()` whenever you want to redraw the menu. See example:

```
public void someFunction() {
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (itemRemovalNeeded) {
        menu.removeItem(R.id.myItem);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Refer:
[Android Activity Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu))